# openzeppelin safeMint erc721 to a gnosis safe

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin, polygon

I have deployed a pretty standard ERC721 contract from openzeppelin.

I can safemint without problems to a normal wallet/address  but when i try to safemint using a gnosis safe as a destination it doesnt seem to work.

Can anyone shed some light as to why this is happening?

I have tried sending existing NFT's to/from the gnosis safe and that works fine.

Also permissions seem to be all fine.

On defender i just get the following:

[image]

Comment: SafeMint will ensure that the contract you are sending the token to implement IERC721 receiver. It's probably not implementing it. You can just do a regular mint and it should work.